# Global variables in .h file vs .cpp file

Tags: c++, openframeworks

I have a question when I use openframeworks. Actually maybe it's some basic question about C++ but I couldn't figure out how I can search it. If someone give me some advice, it would be very appreciated.

When I write the global variable `string bufferTxt` inside ofApp.cpp like:

ofApp.cpp

```
#include "ofApp.h"

string bufferTxt;

void ofApp::setup(){
    string path = ofToDataPath("test.txt");
    ifstream ifs(path.c_str());
    ofBuffer buffer(ifs);
    bufferTxt = buffer.getText();
}

void ofApp::draw(){
    ofBackground(0);
    ofDrawBitmapString(bufferTxt, ofPoint(10, 10));
}
```

It worked.

---

However, if I write the global variable `string bufferTxt` in the header file ofApp.h like:

ofApp.h

```
#pragma once
#include "ofMain.h"

class ofApp : public ofBaseApp{
    public:
    void setup();
    void draw();
    string bufferTxt;
};
```

ofApp.cpp

```
#include "ofApp.h"

void ofApp::setup(){
    string path = ofToDataPath("test.txt");
    ifstream ifs(path.c_str());
    ofBuffer buffer(ifs);
    bufferTxt = buffer.getText();
}

void ofApp::draw(){
    ofBackground(0);
    ofDrawBitmapString(bufferTxt, ofPoint(10, 10));
}
```

It doesn't work.
It was successfully compiled but had an error saying:

```
 *** error for object 0xa0592bdc: pointer being freed was not allocated***
```

What's different between these and why the latter doesn't work?

Thanks

Comment: No global variables should be in the .h file.

Comment: Both of these should work ... I believe there must be some other error.  If you use `ofBufferFromFile` (http://openframeworks.cc/documentation/utils/ofBuffer.html) rather than the custom ifstream, does it help?  I'm wondering if the call to buffer.getText() is returning invalid data.

Comment: @EvanCarslake Sorry my bad. The latter is maybe not actually global variables, but inside `public ofBaseApp` class.

Comment: @bakercp Thanks for your reply. When I used ofBufferFromFile  the situation was same. (I just used ifstream because ofToDataPath was not really working for  my actual code.) It's strange all works well when I declare `string bufferTxt` in .cpp file. Maybe I'm still missing some basic idea of C++ (I usually write javascript).

Comment: On thing to note -- if you use `ofToDataPath("test.txt")` it will give you a relative path.  `std::ifstream` will expect an absolute path.  To get an absolute path from ofToDataPath, use something like `ofToDataPath("test.txt", true);`

Comment: The other thing to look at -- make sure that your project is totally "cleaned" before recompiling.  I really can't figure out where that pointer problem would be coming from (as the member variable approach is how I would do it -- avoid global variables in c++ if you can).  What could be happening is that if you don't clean your project, some of the intermediate object files could still reference the global version, then when it's not there on a recompile with the second version, it gets confused.

Comment: @bakercp Yes, I cleaned and it worked! How silly I was... Probably the reason was what exactly you said. But anyway, thanks for your help!